# getUidRxBytes and getUidTxBytes is inaccurate in Android 6.0 or sometimes when i use a certain app in Android 5.0

Tags: android, network-traffic

my device is nexus 6, when i use getUidRxBytes and getUidTxBytes to get traffic flow for a certain app at a certain time. I found that the results from getUidRxBytes + getUidTxBytes is larger than what i uses.I just listen a song ,the result of getUidRxBytes + getUidTxBytes is 17MB。This is not accurate. Can I know why? thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Various application are running in the background which are consuming data regularly. I think you should see data consumed by a particular application which may be a music app in your case. You need to use `TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(UID)` to get the received data used by an application because `TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes()` gives you total data received by phone from its last reboot. First get the package name for which you want to get Received and Transmitted data.

```
 // handlers for getting traffic information
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;
    int UID;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         //get a list of installed apps.
            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(
                    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("put your package name here")){

                    //get the UID for the selected app
                    UID = packageInfo.uid;
                    break; //found a match, don't need to search anymore
                } }


    // --------------- networking data related --------
    mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
    if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
        alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
        alert.show();
    } else {
        //Function is called here to get the traffic data
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
```

}//onCreate

Put this code outside the `onCreate()`. This will run each second and will show you average value of transmitted and received data in KB in the logcat. Further, you can also print value total KB used

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

    int count = 1;
    long received_data_kb_total;
    long received_data_kb_avg;

    long sent_data_kb_total;
    long sent_data_kb_avg;

    public void run() {

        received_data_kb_total = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(UID)/1024;
        received_data_kb_avg = received_data_kb_total/count;


        sent_data_kb_total = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(UID)/1024;
        sent_data_kb_avg = sent_data_kb_total/count;

        count += 1;

        Log.d("network", "avg received bytes are    :" + received_data_kb_avg + "Kb/s" );
        Log.d("network", "avg transmitted bytes are :" + sent_data_kb_avg + "Kb/s");


        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

replace `put your package name here` with the package name of your music app.